# What does the grep switch --color=auto do?

Tags: windows, command-line, grep, gnuwin32

What effect does `auto` as an option for the `--color` switch have in grep? When does grep decide to color the the matching strings, and when doesn't it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Expected behavior

With `--color=auto`, grep will highlight matching strings if (and only if) the output is written directly to the terminal and said terminal is capable of displaying colored output.

Normally, `--color=auto` is what you want. If, e.g., you use grep to match a URL and pipe it to Wget, Wget will see `\e[1;31mhttp://...` instead of the actual URL (and choke on it).

The following commands should result in colored output:

```
echo Super User | grep --color=auto Super
echo Super User | grep --color=always Super | cat
```

This command, however, should not:

```
echo Super User | grep --color=auto Super | cat
```

Any inconsistency with this behavior should be considered a bug.

#### Source code

With `--color=auto`, the latest [Grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) version (2.5.4) – as well as the original 2.5.4 it is based on – color the output if and only if the condition

```
isatty(STDOUT_FILENO) && getenv("TERM") && strcmp(getenv("TERM"), "dumb")
```

is true, i.e., if and only if the output is being written to a terminal, the [environment variable `TERM`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/7/term/) is defined and the terminal is not [dumb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal#Dumb_terminal).

This won't produce the desired behavior under Windows, since `TERM` is normally not defined. An easy solution to this problem is setting the `TERM=windows` in the control panel.

The latest version of [grep](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/) (2.14) fixes this issue by coloring the output if and only if the condition

```
isatty(STDOUT_FILENO) && should_colorize()
```

is true, where `should_colorize()` is defined differently for POSIX and Win32:

For the former, the condition is equivalent to the one of 2.5.4; for the latter, the enviroment variable `TERM` doesn't have to be set (it just can't be `dumb`).

Comment: How does it find out if it writes to the terminal or not?

Comment: There's a C function for that. If you include the header file `sdgstd.h`, `istty(stdout)` returns `0` if the output is redirected to a file.

Comment: I experiment with windows ports of `grep` and `less` from GnuWin project (gnuwin32.sourceforge.net). `cmd.exe` is improved with `ansicon` utility. `less --color=auto` works as expected: uses color when no redirection is applied and does not when output is redirected. But `grep --color=auto` doesn't print escape sequences in both cases.

Comment: I cannot understand why this happens. I thought these utilities have the same code both in unix and windows versions and they are quite old. So they should behave identically.

Comment: That's a bug in GnuWin32's grep then. On Ubuntu, it behaves as I detailed in my answer. While both derive from the same source code, there are always minor adjustments that have to be made if you're going to compile on another platform. Also, keep in mind that GnuWin32's current version of grep is 2.5.4. The latest version on Ubuntu is 2.12.

Comment: I've dowloaded sources for grep-2.14, coreutils-8.20, diffutils-3.2, gawk-4.0.1 from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ and haven't found neither `sdgstd` nor `istty` (there are few occurences of `istty` in gawk, but those are not function call but variable names)

Comment: On Windows, you should be able to use `_isatty(_fileno(stdout))`. You need to include either `io.h` or `unistd.h`.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear. I've dowloaded sources for _linux_ versions. And in that _linux_ sources there are no strings like "isatty".

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted to fix the Windows version... It doesn't *have to* be `isatty`; that was just an example. `isatty(fileno(stdout))` would also work, and there are probably a few other ways.

Comment: Actually yes, I'd like to fix the windows version. So I want to understand why is there a difference between versions and how do programs determine whether they write to terminal or not. Are there any other functions besides `istty()` and `_isatty()`?

Comment: It's in `main.c`, line `2185`: `if (color_option == 2) color_option = isatty (STDOUT_FILENO) && should_colorize ();`

Comment: I finally figured out. `grep` not only calls `isatty()`, it check for environment variable `TERM` (unlike `ls`). If it is undefined (under windows it is usually) then `grep` doesn't use colors. Under linux there are also some situations when `TERM` is undefined.

Comment: Edited the answer. Couple of notes: 1) there is no function `istty`, maybe misprint and 2) I don't know why I wrote `less` above, I meant `ls` :-). @dennis thanks for the help!

Comment: could you please add this change to the answer? http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/50586

Comment: I've edited my answer to incorporate the information you mentioned. The `istty` function does exist, but it's part of [Thinkage GCOS](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/index.shtml), not the standard libraries.